# What is the best way to implement a parent applications controller or namespace controller in backbone.js?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, backbone.js

Example apps like James Yu's (http://www.jamesyu.org/2011/01/27/cloudedit-a-backbone-js-tutorial-by-example/) provide excellent examples of how to integrate rails with backbone, but what if you want 10 controllers? or 30?

Comment: I'm actually looking for an answer to this as well. Even the DocumentCloud app itself only implements one controller.

Comment: To clarify, on a single page you want to have 10-30 controllers? Can you identify a use case for me.

Comment: Well his style seems to be matching rails controllers to backbone controllers. If you had that many would the solution be to simply instantiate them all in application.js?

Comment: If you have 10 restful controllers in rails, that would be 10 models and 10 collections. Client side controllers != srver side controllers .

Comment: You don't need to integrate Rails with backbone when JavaScript is a major part of your View. Backbone offers unobtrusive modules for writing your own JavaScript. If you're writing your routes RESTful, then you'd really only need one controller or piggy back your actions with `responds_to`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am having trouble understanding what exactly your question is.  We are building a backbone.js-based client for a Rails 3 backend.  We are new to backbone.js too, but our app structure conforms similarly to the link you referenced:

```
index.html
js
+- app.js
+- controllers
  +- controller.js
  +- controller1.js
  ...
  +- controllern.js
```

where we augment the Backbone.Controller object with a few methods and strategies specific to our app.

In general, each controller has its own set of client-side routes that its responsible for and is very focused on just those.  We use a minimum number of routes to minimize cases where we have to support bookmarking which would mean we'd have to spin up the whole app again.

Your client does not have to mirror the server's view of the world.  Best practice is to customize the experience for the client application and to compartmentalize server dependencies.

Really not sure if this answers your question, but since you have no answer so far...